# how to read the xml node value dynamically?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I've a static XML something like this. It is basically a kind of configuration.

```
<ScoCodes>
    <element scoCode="C1" foo="fooc1" bar="barc1" />
    <element scoCode="C2" foo="fooc2" bar="barc2" />
        <!-- like these 100 nodes are present -->
</ScoCodes>
```

for a given scoCode, I want to know what is its `foo` value and `bar` value?

Since it is static, Do I need to parse once in a static block and convert it to some kind of DTO and put the DTOs in a Collection(List, Set etc) so that the elements(DTOs) can be easily searched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
String xmlSource = "your xml";
String xpathExpression = "//element[@scoCode='C1']/@foo | //element[@scoCode='C1']/@bar";

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
StringReader reportConfigurationXML = new StringReader(xmlSource);
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(reportConfigurationXML);

String result = (String) xpath.evaluate(xpathExpression, inputSource, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Cheers,
Borut

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at this tutorial, It describes how to parse XML file](http://java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152)

You can parse XML and store it into list of Objects and make it accessible easily.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use XPath expressions. To select all the foo attribute you can use '//@foo' XPath expression. Once you have all the attributes, you can get their values.

I dont know exact syntax n classes used in Java to do this as I am C# developer.
Hope this will help you. You can get more information about XPath [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).